# Is Microsoft Azure's Access Control service authentication model the same as role based access control?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-authentication

I'm attempting to build an iOS application that can use Microsoft Azure Media Services REST API.  The documentation states that I need to authenticate from the app in order to use the Media Services REST API.  This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-use-aad-auth-to-access-ams-api) also states that the Azure Access Control service authentication model has been deprecated but I'm not sure if that's the same things as RBAC ([Role Based Access Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)).  Has Role Based Access Control been deprecated?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between roles and scopes in Azure's role-based access control (RBAC)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75850554/what-is-the-difference-between-roles-and-scopes-in-azures-role-based-access-con)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Azure Access Control (AAC) is not the same thing as Role-based Access Control (RBAC).

This document states that AAC is not only deprecated, but will be retired on 2018-11-07 (less than 6 months from now) so you should not use it.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-acs-migration
>
> Azure Access Control, a service of Azure Active Directory (Azure AD), will be retired on November 7, 2018. This article describes recommendations for current customers, as you plan to deprecate your use of Access Control. If you don't currently use Access Control, you don't need to take any action.

Regarding Azure Media Services, this document also specifically instructs Media Services application developers to migrate to Azure AD authentication.

RBAC is a component of Azure AD authentication, whereas AAC is from the "old-school" Azure when Azure was all about "Cloud services" (which are also deprecated). This article explains RBAC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview